# Navigation Guard on PhoneCallTask when user clicks "dont call"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I protect my calls to the phone call taks with a bool to stop double taps. My code looks something like:

```
public bool InNavigation { get; set; }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    InNavigation = false;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!InNavigation)
    {
        PhoneCallTask task = new PhoneCallTask()
        {
            DisplayName = "TEst",
            PhoneNumber = "1234567890"
        };
        InNavigation = true;
        task.Show();
    }
}
```

I noticed today that if the user clicks "Dont call" on the MessageBox popup. The code above is relying on the page to be NavigatedFrom and then in NavigateTo the InNavigation flag is reset. This means if the user:

- Clicks "Call" button in my app
- "Don't call" on the Task MessageBox
- Then tries to click "Call" again nothing will happen.

Is there a better way to protect from multi clicks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, add the action to the Dispatcher:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    PhoneCallTask task = new PhoneCallTask()
    {
        DisplayName = "TEst",
        PhoneNumber = "1234567890"
    };
    task.Show();
});
```

This will prevent double-clicks to break navigation. In general, you should *always* use the Dispatcher for Tasks, Launchers, and Navigation.